# Code works fine on it's own, but not when included in my form

Tags: php

I have 2 files: **add.php** (a form to add a recipe into a database, and **numbers.php** (a list for displaying ingredient options).

Both scripts/pages work separately...but when I include ('numbers.php') the onchange code does not work.

```
//numbers.php
<form name="numbers" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="select" onchange="javascript: document.numbers.submit();">
  <option value=0>-</option>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>
</select>
</form>
<?php
$num_ingredients = $_REQUEST["select"];
$count = 0;
while ($count < $num_ingredients) {
  $count++;
  include ('../ingredients/list.php');
  echo '<br />';
}
?>

//add.php
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
Recipe Title:
  <input type="text" name="recipe_name" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $recipe_name; ?>" /><br />
Ingredients:
  <?php include ('numbers.php'); ?><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Recipe" />
<input type="button" onclick="history.go(0)" value="Clear" /><br />
</form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as always :)

------- EDIT --------------------------------------

Here is the page source from add.php as requested

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>POWERCHEF</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="distribution" content="iu">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
  <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2012">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ON WITH THE SHOW --><h3>ADD RECIPE</h3><html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/kitchen/recipes/add.php" method="POST">

Recipe Title:
  <input type="text" name="recipe_name" maxlength="30"
  value="" /><br />
Subtitle:
  <input type="text" name="recipe_subtitle" maxlength="50"
  value="" /><br />
Category:
  <input type="text" name="recipe_category" maxlength="50"
  value="" /><br />
Subcategory:
  <input type="text" name="recipe_subcategory" maxlength="50"
  value="" /><br />
  <br />
Photo:<br />
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
  <input type="file" name="recipe_photo" value="" /><br />
  <br />
Ingredients:<br />
  <form name="numbers" method="post"
  action="/kitchen/recipes/add.php">
<select name="select" onchange="javascript: document.numbers.submit();">
  <option value=0>-</option>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>
  <option value=5>5</option>
  <option value=6>6</option>
  <option value=7>7</option>
  <option value=8>8</option>
  <option value=9>9</option>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=11>11</option>
  <option value=12>12</option>
  <option value=13>13</option>
  <option value=14>14</option>
  <option value=15>15</option>
  <option value=16>16</option>
  <option value=17>17</option>
  <option value=18>18</option>
  <option value=19>19</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
  <option value=21>21</option>
  <option value=22>22</option>
  <option value=23>23</option>
  <option value=24>24</option>
  <option value=25>25</option>
  <option value=26>26</option>
  <option value=27>27</option>
  <option value=28>28</option>
  <option value=29>29</option>
  <option value=30>30</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<br />
Prep Instructions:<br />
  <textarea name="recipe_prep_instructions" class="" cols="88" rows="15"
  value="" /></textarea><br />
  <br />
Cooking Instructions:<br />
  <textarea name="recipe_prep_instructions" class="" cols="88" rows="15"
  value="" /></textarea><br />
  <br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Recipe" />
<input type="button" onclick="history.go(0)" value="Clear" /><br />
<br />
</form>
</html>
<footer>
  <p>
    <small><strong>&copy; 2012 </strong> -&nbsp;All Rights Reserved</small>
  </p>
</footer>
<!-- THANKS FOR STOPPING BY! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is being returned by numbers.php

Comment: nothing is being returned when included, but on it's own, numbers.php returns one dropdown list per the number/amount selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the form on add.php did not have a name

Comment: I see that you solved it, make sure you're not submitting the outer form, as that might cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
<input type="text" name="recipe_name" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $recipe_name"; ?>" /><br />
```

Should be: (notice the removal of the quote in the php block)

```
 <input type="text" name="recipe_name" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $recipe_name; ?>" /><br />
```

The quote could possibly be messing up the other script.

EDIT:
Ok, was this also just a copy paste typo?

```
<form name="numbers" method="post action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Should be:

```
<form name="numbers" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

EDIT2:
Ok, the problem is that the form "numbers" is inside the other form, so it's having trouble accesing it with `document.numbers`. To fix it you are going to need to access it a different way, such as giving it an id and using `getElementById`.

Comment: damn...sorry dude, yea that was a copy/paste type-o.  the original code was correct there too.  i don't know how to copy and paste code on stackoverflow, so i must've screwed up while retyping.  sorry about that.  the main issue is surrounding the javascript - it works fine on numbers.php, but not when included in add.php

Comment: Can you paste the resulting page source for when it's included?

Comment: not sure if that's what you wanted...but i added it to the op.  thanks again for your help!